# How to merge duplicate rows without deleting rows

Tags: postgresql, merge, duplicates

There might be similar questions but I have not found answers yet.

I have tables below

```
id | lang_code |  name
1010522747 | CHT | Si Li Ai Guang You Zhi Yuan
1010522747 | ENG | Si Li Ai Guang Kindergarten
1010522758 | CHT | Tai Bei Shi Li Wen Hu Guo Min Xiao Xue
1010522758 | ENG | Tai Bei Shi Li Wen Hu Elementary School
1010522760 | CHT | Xiang He Yao Ju
1010522760 | ENG | Xiang He Pharmacy
1010522754 | CHT | Guan Shan De Bian Dang
1010522758 | CHT | Tai Bei Shi Li Wen Hu Guo Min Xiao Xue
```

Basically the data is about local store's name in Taiwan and not all rows have English or Transliterated name.
(in other words, in some cases there are only transliterated name instead of having both English and Transliterated name)

What I want is that
I want the rows to be easily join-able using id field.
For instance,

so this is the code i did so far.

```
select id, lang_code, (case when lang_code = 'ENG' then name_dp end) as name_en, 
(case when lang_code = 'CHT' then name_dp end) as name_trans
```

And the result is below

```
id | lang_code |  name_en | name_trans
1010522747 | CHT | NULL              | Si Li Ai Guang You Zhi Yuan
1010522747 | ENG |Si Li Ai Guang Kindergarten | NULL
1010522749 | CHT | NULL              | A Cai Yu Chi Rou Geng
1010522750 | CHT | NULL              | Ju Jiang Dian Nao
1010522754 | CHT | NULL              | Guan Shan De Bian Dang
1010522758 | CHT | NULL              | Tai Bei Shi Li Wen Hu Guo Min Xiao Xue
1010522758 | ENG | Tai Bei Shi Li Wen Hu Elementary School | NULL
```

I want the result to be same as below.

```
id | name_merged
1010522747 | Si Li Ai Guang Kindergarten | Si Li Ai Guang You Zhi Yuan
1010522749 | A Cai Yu Chi Rou Geng
1010522750 | Ju Jiang Dian Nao
1010522754 | Guan Shan De Bian Dang
1010522758 | Tai Bei Shi Li Wen Hu Elementary School | Tai Bei Shi Li Wen Hu Guo Min Xiao Xue
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I just came out with very simple solution 'self join'

this is the code

```sql
select a.poi_id, coalesce(a.name_dp, b.name_dp) as name_merged, a.name_dp as name_en, b.name_dp as name_trans
from MYTABLE as a
left join MYTABLE as b
on a.id = b.id and b.lang_code = 'CHT'
where a.lang_code = 'ENG'
```